# Rails/Postgres Concat JSONB keys together in select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How can I obtain an aggregate of different keys within a JSONB column? Some of the data I want to show in the aggregated form would be a count & total (easy) but the other would be an array of a concatenation of two keys. I keep getting an error when trying to concat them within the inline sql.

```
context.request_groups
       .joins(:request_items)
       .select("request_groups.id as id, 
                count(*) as count, 
                array_agg(request_items.data->>'contact_first_name' || ' ' || request_items.data->>'contact_last_name') as names,
                sum(cast(request_items.data->>'amount' as float)) as total")
       .group(:id)
```

I'm currently trying to use the `ARRAY_AGG` function (example: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg-function/) and getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown)
LINE 1: ...t_name' || ' ' || request_items.data->>'contac...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm looking for results like:

`id, count, total, ['first last', 'first last']`

Heres the table layout:

```
---------------------- 
Request Group
---------------------- 
id         | UUID 
created_at | Timestamp
----------------------

---------------------- 
Request Items
---------------------- 
id       | UUID
group_id | UUID
data     | JSONB
----------------------
```

JSONB layout:

```
id: 3,
group_id: 2
data:
  { 
    "name"=>"Fun Event",
    "amount"=>200,
    "contact_first_name"=>"Jeff",
    "contact_last_name"=>"Person" 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following one should work I hope, there was problem in your code where  constructing expression in `array_agg` method. Just adding open and close brackets will solve the issue.

Old one: `request_items.data->>'contact_first_name'` 
Updated one: `(request_items.data ->> 'contact_first_name')`

If brackets not used, there would be problem in distinguish arguments of `array_agg` method.

```
context.request_groups
    .joins(:request_items)
    .select("request_groups.id as id,
                count(*) as count,
                array_agg( (request_items.data ->> 'contact_first_name') || ' ' || (request_items.data ->> 'contact_last_name') ) as names,
                sum(cast(request_items.data->>'amount' as float)) as total")
    .group(:id)
```